# How to create a dropdown based on selection in another dropdown in php?

Tags: php, oracle, dropdown

This is the first time that I’m working with oracle. I’m kind of stuck at printing the values of the second dropdown on the page. I’m getting the right results in the browser’s response tab but I’m not sure why it is not getting printed on the main page. Upon selecting a value in the first dropdown, it should print the names in the second one.

Here's my code:

form.php

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="addroles" class="hide" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <div id="resultRoleContent"></div>
        </div>  
             <form class="cmxform" action ='functions/processform.php' id="Form1" method="post">
           <legend> Faculty Transaction Form</legend>
            <label for="addname">Please Select School</label>
           <select class="form-control" name="school" id="school">
                <?php
                $nameslist = $getschool->getSchool();
                oci_execute($nameslist, OCI_DEFAULT);
                while ($row = oci_fetch_array($nameslist, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $row['SCHOOLNAME'] . '">' . $row['SCHOOLNAME']. '</option>';
                }
                ?>
           </select>
            <label for="names">Please Select Name</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="names" id="names">
               <option value='0' >Select Name</option>

        </select>
            
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#school').change(function(){
 var schoolname = $(this).val();
 $('#names').find('option').not(':first').remove();
 // AJAX request
 $.ajax({
   url: 'getUsers.php',
   type: 'post',
   data: {request: 1, primaryschool: schoolname},
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(response){
     var len = response.length;

     for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
       var firstname = response[i]['FIRSTNAME'];
       $("#names").append("<option value='"+firstname+"'>"+firstname+"</option>");
     }

   }
    });

  });
  });
</script>
```

getUsers.php

```
<?php
$dbUser = "xxxx";
$dbPass = "xxxx";
$dbConn = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxxx)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=xxxx)))";
$conn = oci_connect($dbUser, $dbPass, $dbConn);
$request = 0;
if(isset($_POST['request'])){
  $request = $_POST['request'];
 }
if($request == 1){
   $schoolpropername = $_POST['primaryschool'];
   $sql =oci_parse($conn,"SELECT * FROM person Where primaryschool = :primaryschool Order by firstname");
   oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':primaryschool', $schoolname);
   oci_execute($sql);
    ?>
   <select class="form-control" name="names" id="names">
    <?php
    while($result = oci_fetch_array($sql, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)){
    echo '<option value="' . $result['FIRSTNAME'] . '">' . $result['FIRSTNAME']. '</option>';

  }    
   
}

?>
</select>
```

I'm getting the right results in the browsers response tab. It is only not getting printed on the web page. There's no error in the error_log. I referred to a few similar questions as well but didn't get the answer hence posted it.

Comment: I think you just need to append the response. The response should be the select tag with options.

Comment: How do I do that? Can you update/answer with the code please?

Comment: @HAM Also i noticed that you are `expected` to get response in `json` (`ajax -> dataType: 'json'`), format, but you return plain html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this:

**SCRIPT**

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#school').change(function(){
         var schoolname = $(this).val();
         $('#names').find('option').not(':first').remove();
         // AJAX request
         $.ajax({
           url: 'getUsers.php',
           type: 'post',
           data: {request: 1, primaryschool: schoolname},
           success: function(response){
              $("select#names").html('<option value="0">Select Name</option>');
              $("select#names").append(response);
           }
       });    
    });
 });
</script>
```

**getUsers.php**

```
<?php
$dbUser = "xxxx";
$dbPass = "xxxx";
$dbConn = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxxx)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=utf8devl)))";
$conn = oci_connect($dbUser, $dbPass, $dbConn);
$request = 0;
if(isset($_POST['request'])){
  $request = $_POST['request'];
 }
if($request == 1){
   $schoolpropername = $_POST['primaryschool'];
   $sql =oci_parse($conn,"SELECT * FROM person Where primaryschool = :primaryschool Order by firstname");
   oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':primaryschool', $schoolname);
   oci_execute($sql);
   $response = '';

   while($result = oci_fetch_array($sql, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)){
    $response .= '<option value="' . $result['FIRSTNAME'] . '">' . $result['FIRSTNAME']. '</option>' . PHP_EOL;

  }    
   echo $response;
}
```

Also this can be done using `JSON` response:

**getUsers.php**

```
...
$response = [];
    
while($result = oci_fetch_array($sql, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)){
   $response[] = $result['FIRSTNAME'];  
}    
echo json_encode($response);
...
```

**Jquery**

```
...    
$.ajax({
   url: 'getUsers.php',
   type: 'post',
   data: {request: 1, primaryschool: schoolname},
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(response){
      $("select#names").html('<option value="0">Select Name</option>');
      var arr = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
      $.each( arr, function( key, value ) {
         $("select#names").append('<option value="'+ value +'">'+ value +'</option>');
      });          
   }
});
...
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the confirmation produced on my localhost:

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#school').change(function(){
                    var schoolname = $(this).val();
                    $('#names').find('option').not(':first').remove();
                    // AJAX request
                    $.ajax({
                      url: 'resourse.php',
                      type: 'post',
                      data: {request: 1, primaryschool: schoolname},
                      success: function(response){
                         $("select#depend").html('<option value="0">Select Name</option>');
                         $("select#depend").append(response);
                      }
                  });    
               });
            });        
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="school">
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
        </select>
        <select id="depend">
            
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

**resourse.php**

```
<?php
$array = [
    "Alex",
    "Peter",
    "Sara"
];
$out = '';

foreach ($array as $val){
    $out .= '<option value="' . $val . '">' . $val. '</option>' . PHP_EOL;
}

echo $out;
```

The above example work as expected.

Comment: Hey, it didn't work either. The output remains the same i.e it gets printed in the response tab but on the main page :(

Comment: @HAM See my change in ajax. Try to point up exactly the form control. Also make sure you do not have same `element ID` `id="names"` somewhere else in your `html` code.

Comment: @HAM See also how you can do this using `Json` response.

Comment: Hey, it doesnt work. I tried the first way, but the dropdown is empty. In the response tab, it gets fetched.There is no error in the error log

Comment: @HAM Try to give to select an unique id like `id="names1234"` and make a correction in jquery to specified id `$('select#names1234')`

Comment: @HAM I just updated my answer with example which work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you tell how to make one more dropdown based on the selection in dropdown 1. So I am trying to make two dropdowns based on selection in the first dropdown